# How to add "Copy" option to text?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit

I have a text in a "bubble" by fitting the text inside an image as shown below. it works fine except the text is not copyable. I need to have "copy" option so that when user tab on the text (or bubble image") "cop" options is displayed, just like in when user tab into the built in SMS Message bubble.

```
#import "SpeechBubbleView.h"

static UIFont* font = nil;
static UIImage* lefthandImage = nil;
static UIImage* righthandImage = nil;

const CGFloat VertPadding = 4;       // additional padding around the edges
const CGFloat HorzPadding = 4;

const CGFloat TextLeftMargin = 17;   // insets for the text
const CGFloat TextRightMargin = 15;
const CGFloat TextTopMargin = 10;
const CGFloat TextBottomMargin = 11;

const CGFloat MinBubbleWidth = 50;   // minimum width of the bubble
const CGFloat MinBubbleHeight = 40;  // minimum height of the bubble

const CGFloat WrapWidth = 200;       // maximum width of text in the bubble

@implementation SpeechBubbleView

+ (void)initialize
{
    if (self == [SpeechBubbleView class])
    {
        font = /*[*/ [UIFont systemFontOfSize:[UIFont systemFontSize]] /*retain]*/;

        lefthandImage = /*[*/ [[UIImage imageNamed:/*@"BubbleLefthand"*/@"lefttest4"]
            stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:20 topCapHeight:19] /*retain]*/;

        righthandImage = /*[*/[[UIImage imageNamed:/*@"BubbleRighthand"*/@"righttest4"]
            stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:20 topCapHeight:19] /*retain]*/;
    }
}

+ (CGSize)sizeForText:(NSString*)text
{
    CGSize textSize = [text sizeWithFont:font
        constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(WrapWidth, 9999)
        lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    CGSize bubbleSize;
    bubbleSize.width = textSize.width + TextLeftMargin + TextRightMargin;
    bubbleSize.height = textSize.height + TextTopMargin + TextBottomMargin;

    if (bubbleSize.width < MinBubbleWidth)
        bubbleSize.width = MinBubbleWidth;

    if (bubbleSize.height < MinBubbleHeight)
        bubbleSize.height = MinBubbleHeight;

    bubbleSize.width += HorzPadding*2;
    bubbleSize.height += VertPadding*2;

    return bubbleSize;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [self.backgroundColor setFill];
    UIRectFill(rect);

    CGRect bubbleRect = CGRectInset(self.bounds, VertPadding, HorzPadding);

    CGRect textRect;
    textRect.origin.y = bubbleRect.origin.y + TextTopMargin;
    textRect.size.width = bubbleRect.size.width - TextLeftMargin - TextRightMargin;
    textRect.size.height = bubbleRect.size.height - TextTopMargin - TextBottomMargin;

    if (bubbleType == BubbleTypeLefthand)
    {
        [lefthandImage drawInRect:bubbleRect];
        textRect.origin.x = bubbleRect.origin.x + TextLeftMargin;
    }
    else
    {
        [righthandImage drawInRect:bubbleRect];
        textRect.origin.x = bubbleRect.origin.x + TextRightMargin;
    }

    [[UIColor blackColor] set];
    [text drawInRect:textRect withFont:font lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
}

- (void)setText:(NSString*)newText bubbleType:(BubbleType)newBubbleType
{
    //[text release];
    /**
     handle local
     **/

   // text = [newText copy];

    text = [newText copy];

    bubbleType = newBubbleType;
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    //[text release];
    //[super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: Why don't you use an `UITextView` or `UITextField` as a subview instead? You can use `UIMenuController` of course, but I'm not sure you want to hack all this together manually.

Comment: Thanks, ... if I use UITextView, could I hide the rectangle box so that only text appear inside the bubble (not inside a textview box)?

Comment: @userXXX `UITextView` has a clear background by default, I don't understand what your problem is.

Comment: yes, i tried it and it works, except it display "paste" when user tab on the textview, I need it to display "copy" instead. How do I control that?

Comment: @userXXX make the text view readonly and it will no longer offer the "paste" option.

Comment: thanks ... but i'm not sure how to make TextView readonly... could you please elaborate.

Comment: @userXXX Sorry, this is getting tiring... you could set a property called something like "editable" or whatever, but please google it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the system cut/copy/paste menu (or some subset thereof) without the full suite of text editability features from `UITextField` or `UITextView`, you need to present your own [`UIMenuController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UIMenuController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIMenuController). Doing this requires:

- the control to be affected by the menu can become first responder
- said control (or something sensible in the responder chain above it) implements the editing methods (e.g. `copy:`) you want to support
- you perform some event handling to present the menu controller at an appropriate time (e.g. a gesture recognizer action)

As is often the case, there's [a good tutorial on NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/uimenucontroller/) with both Swift and ObjC sample code. Kudos to @mattt, though I'd say this line needs a correction:

> If you’re wondering why, *oh why*, this isn’t just built into `UILabel`, well… join the club.

"Join the club" should be replaced with "[file a bug](http://bugreport.apple.com)". It even sorta almost rhymes!